# Subset a data on rows of IDs with conditional column values and create a row with NA where necessary

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset, tidyr

I have data that includes four essential elements: ID, Time, exposure, outcome

I want to have a scatterplot between my exposure and outcome but the timepoint of interest for my exposure is different from the timepoint of interest for the outcome and thus there are some IDs that do not have any assessment at that outcome timepoint. What I want to do is create a subset of data with each ID as a row, then exposure at time-1 and outcome at time-3 but if an ID doesn`t have an assessment at time-3 I have it included with the value NA. The issue is that in the data if a timepoint was not assessed, the relative row for that ID doesn`t exist in the first place.
Here is an example of the data:

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)
exposure <-c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 2.1, 2.2, 3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2)
outcome <-c(0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 2.1, 3.1)
Time<-c("time_1","time_2","time_1","time_2","time_3","time_1","time_2","time_3","time_1","tme_2")
data <-data.frame(ID,exposure,outcome,Time)
```

Why I am doing this because the scatter plot is a cross-sectional plot and thus if I just plot based on time per ID, the plot would be empty because there would be no pair in each row with exposure at time_1 and outcome at time_3 so that is why I need to create a subset of data and making the paires myself.

I tried these codes so far:

```
# so you see the empty cells and the reason of getting an empty plot
df <- data |> pivot_wider (name_from = Time, values_from = c(exposure,outcome))

#subsetting the data to only my desired time points (this helps me to see in my actual # data which IDs are actually not having an assessed time point

df1 <- data %>%
group_by(ID)%>%
filter(data, Time=="time_1" | Time=="time_3")%>%
ungroup()

# And eventually subsetting the data based on different timepoint to then merge them #together

df2 <- filter (data, Time=="time_1")
df3 <- filter (data, Time=="time_3")
```

But in the last code, you see the size of the two datasets are different and apart from that, it is clinically important for me to show that for instance for ID=1, the outcome has NA at time_3, so I don`t want to just subset on those IDs with both values available.

So the dataset that I want to eventually have, needs to have the following structure:

```
ID exposure_time_1  outcome_time_3
----------------------------------
1         1.2            NA
2         1.4            0.4
3         2.2            0.1
4         5.2            NA
```

Does anyoe has any solution on this?

Comment: maybe look into `case_when()`.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.  Just `select` the columns after you `pivot_wider`.

```
df %>% 
    select(ID, exposure_time_1,  outcome_time_3) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(exposure_time_1) | !is.na(outcome_time_3))
```

Your dataset didn't need it here, but I added the `filter` to make sure that at least one of the last two columns is non-empty.  Perhaps you actually want `filter(!is.na(outcome_time_3))`, though.